# Using level curves, conclude that $\ \lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}f(x,y)=\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}$ does not exist

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

So I tried sketching some level curves of$\ f$ and came to the conclusion that all the level curves of$\ f$ are circles that pass through the origin, but how can I conclude, just by looking at the level curves, that

$$\ \lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}f(x,y)=\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}$$

doesn't exist?

Comment: If all the level curves pass through the origin, then the limit can't be independent of the manner of approach, so the limit doesn't exist. (If you approach along a specific level curve, your "answer" will be the constant value on that level curve; you can't get more than one "answer" if the limit is to exist.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a (continuous) level curve of $f(x,y) = V$ passes through some point $(x_0,y_0)$ and is continuous at $(x_0,y_0)$, then the limit, as $x,y)$ approaches $(x_0,y_0)$ along that curve, of  $f(x_0,y_0)$ has to be equal to $V$.

So if the limit you are looking for exists, the level curve $f(x,y) = 1$ says the limit must be $1$.  But the level curve $f(x,y) =  2$ says the limit must be $2$. Therefore, the limit cannot exist.